# How would I approach solving this improper integral using a Riemann integral?

Tags: calculus

> $$\int_1^\infty \frac1{x^2}\mathrm dx$$

We're asked what happens if we use the typical Riemann integral as defined on this improper integral. We can't use typical Riemann integrals to solve improper integrals, so to make it finite we would use a dummy variable as $y$ goes to infinity, then solve it as $-\frac1y+1=1$, but what else is this question asking in using the Riemann definition?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Riemann integral is only defined for closed and bounded intervals, it does not make sense to use the Riemann integral here. Indeed, as you noted, one has to make use of the "improper" Riemann integral which involves taking a limit. More precisely, the symbol $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$ should be interpreted as the limit
\begin{align*}
\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x = \lim_{y \to \infty}\int_1^y\frac{1}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&= \lim_{y \to \infty} \left[ \left.-\frac{1}{x}\right\vert_{x=1}^{x=y} \right]\\
&= \lim_{y \to \infty} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{y}\right)\\
&= 1.
\end{align*}
The idea here is partially extend the Riemann integral (which, again, is only defined on bounded intervals) to "nice functions" on possibly unbounded intervals by taking a limit. Thus, an improper integral is really just a limit of Riemann integrals. This is likely what is meant by "using the Riemann integral".

As for what the question means by "what happens if we use the typical Riemann definition", my guess is that the purpose of that question is to point out that the definition of the Riemann integral only applies with *bounded intervals*.